# Why is this true - $\int_C \frac{1}{z^n} dz = 0$ if $n \ne 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I was looking up the reasoning behind the residue theorem and was wondering what was so significant about the $a_{-1}$ coefficient of the Laurent series and I came across this result -

$$\int_C \frac{1}{z^n} dz = 0$$
if $n \ne 1$

Why is this true? Is there a name for this result like there is for many complex analysis results (Cauchy's Integral Formula, etc...)

**Edit**

Also, I can't see how this result actually holds...If we let $z = 0$ then it doesn't matter what value $n$ is, we will have a singularity and this integral won't equal $0$. What am I missing here?

Comment: The function $1/z^{n}$ has an anti-derivative (also called *primitive*) on the punctured plane when $n\neq 1$ (What is it?). Now use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (for complex variables) to deduce that the integral around any closed path has to be zero.

Comment: I know the result about the integral around any closed path is zero if $f(z)$ is analytic inside and on the path. It's the rest of it, in particular why the $a_{-1}$ coefficient has special significance.

Comment: I would say that $a_{-1}$ has a special significance precisely because the function $1/z$ does not have primitive since $\int_{|z|=1} dz/z=2\pi i$. So after integrating the Laurent series, all the terms $1/z^{n}$ with $n\neq 1$ drop out (as they have primitive) except for $n=1$ term. Regarding to your **Edit**: We are integrating over a curve $C$. As long as $C$ does not pass through the origin ($z=0$), the integral is well-defined and there is no singularity issue at all.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to see this, one being the method using primitives that Prism describes in the comments. A more naive way is to first use Green's to replace the curve $C$ with $S^1 = \{z:|z|=1\}$ (so long as $0\notin C$). Then consider 
$$\int_{S^1} z^{-n} dz = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta n } ~ie^{i\theta} d\theta = i\int^{2\pi}_0 e^{i\theta(1-n)}d\theta$$ Finally because $e^{i\theta k}$ is $2\pi$ periodic for $k\neq0$ one can see that the only non-zero case is when $n=1$. In fact it should also be apparent that for any curve C homotopic to $S^1$ in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ that $$\int_C \frac{1}{z}dz = 2\pi i.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result only for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there are a simple way to check it.

Remind... $f^{(n)}(z)={\displaystyle \frac{n!}{2\pi i}}{\displaystyle \int_{C} {\displaystyle \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}}} dw}$ for all z in the interior of $C$, where $C$ is circle.

In the above equation, take $f(w)=1$(constant function), $z=0$.

If $n\geq 1$, then LHS is zero, and we can rewrite above equation as follows:

$0={\displaystyle \int_{C} {\displaystyle \frac{1}{w^{n}}} dw}$ for all $n\geq 2$

Answer (score 1):

Apart from explicitly computing the line integral, as Joe Manlove has done in his answer, you can use the following argument: If an analytic function $f:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb C}$ has an analytic primitive $F:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb C}$ then for any curve $\gamma\subset\Omega$ beginning at $a$ and ending at $b$ one has
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\>dz=F(b)-F(a)\ ,$$
and for any closed curve $\gamma\subset\Omega$ one has $$\int_\gamma f(z)\>dz=0\ .$$
Now apply this to $\Omega:=\dot{\mathbb C}$, $f(z):=z^n$ with $n\ne-1$, $F(z):={\displaystyle{1\over n+1}}z^{n+1}$.